# How to access the types from @rtk-query/codegen-openapi generated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Using `@rtk-query/codegen-openapi` I am able to generate the api types using my static `swagger.json` file my configuration.

openapi-config.ts

```
import type { ConfigFile } from '@rtk-query/codegen-openapi'

const config: ConfigFile = {
    schemaFile: './swagger.json',
    apiFile: 'emptyapi',
    apiImport: 'emptySplitApi',
    outputFiles: {
        'src/pages/main/sample/sample.model.tsx': {
            filterEndpoints: ['sendMessage', 'getSystemDefaults'],
        }
    },
    exportName: 'synkUIAPI',
    hooks: true,
}

export default config
```

sample.model.tsx

```
import { emptySplitApi as api } from "emptyapi";

const injectedRtkApi = api.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getSystemDefaults: build.query<
            GetSystemDefaultsApiResponse,
            GetSystemDefaultsApiArg
        >({
            query: () => ({ url: `/v1/system/defaults` }),
        }),
        sendMessage: build.mutation<SendMessageApiResponse, SendMessageApiArg>({
            query: (queryArg) => ({
                url: `/v1/system/message`,
                method: "POST",
                body: queryArg.body,
            }),
        }),
    }),
    overrideExisting: false,
});
```

```
export type SendMessageApiResponse = unknown;
export type SendMessageApiArg = {
    /** Message */
    body: string;
};
export type LangDto = {
    lastModDate: string;
    lastModBy: string;
    langId: number;
    jLangCode: string;
    jCountryCode: string;
    jVariantCode: string;
    name: string;
};
```

If I'm trying to access the `Langto` in my component file using `tst-reflect` is not woking for me is there any other way to achieve this using `@rtk-query/codegen-openapi`?

For the `tst-reflect` I referred to this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tst-reflect-example-stackoverflow-72682272?file=index.ts) but I am getting `getProperties` as empty in the console. Is there any built-in method to access the `Langto` using `@rtk-query/codegen-openapi`?

I need to access `Langto` in my react component. The expected result should be [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tst-reflect-example-stackoverflow-72682272?file=index.ts).